# Why file upload and cancel on second time disappears the first attachment?

Tags: html, file-upload

Please find the steps,
1. I upload image using html file upload for eg: a.jpg
2. again when I chose the file second time and cancel the pop up, The first   Image chosen(a.jpg) is disappears and no file choosen is coming.

This happens only in chome.

Can anyone tell me why this behaviour is there in chrome?

Thanks-

Comment: Please share your code or a snippet of your problem

Comment: yeah well if i cancel the pop up, it does clear the uploaded file. you should multiple select what you want. Use multiple in your file upload tag

Comment: Please check here  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_fileupload_get

Answer (score 0):

I think when you click the cancel the pop-up, you are cancelling the connection. So no file uploads and you cancel the entire connection.

Comment: You can check here  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_fileupload_get  . It is the default behaviour. but in mozilla it is not happening. 2nd time you dont select any file. you cancel the pop up and see